# list of nsh commands or how to execute remotely linux commands using nsh like rsh

Tags: linux

Can anybody give link to list of nsh commands
And like rsh or ssh how to execute remotely linux commands using nsh

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while looking on Stackoverflow for information about NSH.

The good news is I at least found a list of [NSH Commands](http://kailord.homeip.net/stuffs/Learning%20resources/ACS/BladeLogic%20CBT/BladeLogicNSHCommands.pdf) while searching for information on Google.